# Threadsafe copy constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to make the copy constructor of a class thread safe like this:

```
class Base
{
   public:
      Base ( Base const & other )
      {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock ( other.m_Mutex );
         ...
      }
   protected:
      
      std::mutex m_Mutex;
}

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
      Derived ( Derived const & other ) : Base ( other )
      {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock ( other.m_Mutex );
         ...
      }

}
```

My problem is that in the derived class I need to lock the mutex before the base class constructor call in the initializer list to guarantee consistency. Any idea how I could achieve that?

Regards.

Comment: It does not make much sense to lock the object mutex in the its constructor as there are no other threads except calling thread who has access to memory of newly created object. Instead you should lock `other.m_mutex`

Comment: If you're making a new instance of the class, you don't need to lock that instance, because no other threads should have access to it at that point

Comment: Did you consider to create a factory method which locks the `other` and then creates a copy; the copy ctor instead could be protected....

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko Yeah I made a typo I fixed it tx.

Comment: You've got a recursive problem here. If you solve it for derived, what about derived-form-derived? Probably best to do what Dmytro suggests and get the locking out of the hierarchy completely. That or switch to a recursive mutex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advice of @AnthonyWilliams is to lock the constructor as an argument of a delegated constructor, see [here](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-safe-copy-constructors.html) for the full article:

```
class A
{
private:
  A(const A &a, const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> &)
   : i(a.i), i_squared(a.i_squared) {}
public:
  A(const A &a) : A(a, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(a.mtx)) {}
  ...
};
```

Note that you lock the other object in order to prevent it being changed by another thread during copy (construction of the object itself is [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598311/c-constructor-thread-safety)). Moreover, the same approach is valid for a move constructor.

---

An application to your example could look like this (untested & uncompiled):

```
class Base
{
   public:
      Base(Base const& other) : Base(other, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(other.m_Mutex)) {}   
      virtual ~Base() = default; //virtual destructor!

   protected:
      Base(Base const& other, std::lock_guard<std::mutex> const&) {}

      mutable std::mutex m_Mutex; //should be mutable in order to be lockable from const-ref
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   protected:
      Derived(Derived const& other, std::lock_guard<std::mutex> const& lock)
          : Base(other, lock)
      {}

   public:
      Derived(Derived const& other)
          : Derived(other, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(other.m_Mutex))
      {}
};
```

Comment: Implemented. Works like a charm. Altough I wonder if copy assignment needs to guard this too.

Comment: @Desperado17: for sure you should, basically you should review and potentially adjust any member function. In the case of assignments, you'll even need two locks (or you could use copy-and-swap and utilize the lock in the copy constructor above).

Answer (score 0):

I think about solution where I define two types of the constructor:

- Public copy ctor, which locks and unlocks
- Protected "copy" ctor, which does not lock

The drawback is that it is easy to forget to not call `Base(Base const&, void*)` in the Derived class. If so, that will lead to lock/unlock inconsistency.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Mutex
{
    void lock() { std::cout << "Lock\n"; }
    void unlock() { std::cout << "Unlock\n"; }
};

struct MutexLocker
{
    MutexLocker() = default;
    MutexLocker(Mutex& mutex) { mutex.lock(); }
};

class Base: private MutexLocker
{
public:
    Base() {}

    virtual ~Base() = default;

    Base(Base const& other)
        : Base(other, nullptr)
    {
        mutex_.unlock();
    }
    
protected:
    // Implement copy logic here
    Base(Base const& other, void* tag)
        : MutexLocker(other.mutex_)
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }

protected:
    mutable Mutex mutex_;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived() = default;

    Derived(Derived const& other)
        : Derived(other, nullptr)
    {
        mutex_.unlock();
    }

protected:
    // Implement copy logic here
    Derived(Derived const& other, void* tag)
        : Base(other, tag)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

class DerivedOfDerived: public Derived
{
public:
    DerivedOfDerived() = default;

    DerivedOfDerived(DerivedOfDerived const& other)
        : DerivedOfDerived(other, nullptr)
    {
        mutex_.unlock();
    }

protected:
    // Implement copy logic here
    DerivedOfDerived(Derived const& other, void* tag)
        : Derived(other, tag)
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedOfDerived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedOfDerived d;
    DerivedOfDerived d2 {d};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the place of the object being constructed to lock the object it's copying from.

In your example, there is no way to guarantee `m_Mutex` stays locked between the end of the `Base` constructor and the beginning of the `Derived` constructor (after the initializer list). Not only that, if you write yet another class `DerivedAgain` that derives from `Derived`, you would need to handle its copy constructor too. Moreover, what about the move constructor?

Instead of locking a mutex in a constructor, lock it beforehand, construct your new object, and then unlock it. Probably the easiest way to do this is to write a "factory":

```
Derived Derived::make_copy() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
    return Derived(*from);
}
```

Comment: The drawback is that you cannot use this class in the STL containers, if copy-ctor is disabled and move ctor is not defined

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko You can if you take care not to use the copy constructor without prior locking. `make_copy` is only just a convenience function to use the copy constructor in a thread-safe way.

Comment: If you have many objects in the container, which of them should be locked and in what order during vector resize, for instance? We do not know, it is implementation specific.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko If you have race conditions when managing a container of these objects, I think you have bigger problems. Most likely your overall design needs to be reworked. Or maybe you want a container of pointers instead.